# Angularjs aHref value

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to AngularJS and learning.
I was trying to switch theme CSS files by assigning values to a-href in bootstrap nav dropdown but i have no idea ho to do so.
Kindly guide me... Thanks

```
<html ng-app ng-controller="maincontroller">
<head>
<link href="css/{{theme}}.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li><a href ng-click="theme = black">Black</a></li>
<li><a href ng-click="theme = green">Another action</a></li>
</ul>
```

SCRIPT

```
    var maincontroller = function($scope) {
    $scope.theme = "black";
    };
```

Comment: I don't think this is going to work. Add both CSS theme files and then just add a class to `body` or something like that to apply all of the theme changes

Comment: friend, regardless where i apply the css theme change, the issue is how to update the value of {{theme}} using <a href> or <a ng-href>

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do will work, but you can try using [ng-href](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref) :

> Using Angular markup like {{hash}} in an href attribute will make the
>   link go to the wrong URL if the user clicks it before Angular has a
>   chance to replace the {{hash}} markup with its value. Until Angular
>   replaces the markup the link will be broken and will most likely
>   return a 404 error. The ngHref directive solves this problem.

```
<link href="css/{{theme}}.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Comment: friend can u tell me how to use ng-href to update the value of {{theme}}

Comment: in your mainController you change the value of Theme .. for example, you can create a button and use ng-click to set the $scope.theme to 'black'